# Failed to build these modules: _ctypes - when building Python 3.7

Tags: python, python3, module, non-root-user

I'm trying to build Python 3.7.4 (as a non-root user on an older machine - SLES 11). After `./configure`ing and `make`ing, I get the following message:

```
Failed to build these modules:
_bz2                  _ctypes               _curses_panel
```

I'm most interested in `_cytpes`, since lacking that one gives me trouble later.

What do I need to do, or to have installed, for the building of the `_ctypes` module succeeds? Note that I don't have root privileges.

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue31652 . You need to install libffi-dev or libffi-devel, and if the library is not in your library search path, add an appropriate LDFLAGS arg to ./configure .

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: `LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/dir/with/ffilibs/` ?

Comment: Yes. The user who posted that used both -L and -R options.